# Accessing data from an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using the following method to access data about an object. The first NSLog shows all of the data. The second NSLog shows the 'frame' data which comes out as: NSRect: {{168, 102}, {5, 5}}

How can I access the first set of coordinates from the NSRect and then the abscissa from the first pair?

```
-(void) moveTheShape:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [timer userInfo];
    NSLog(@"Info:  %@",userInfo);
    //Info:  <Shape: 0x68b6c30; frame = (151 352; 5 5); layer = <CALayer: 0x68b6c00>>
    NSDictionary *frame = [userInfo  valueForKey:@"frame"];
    NSLog(@"frame: %@", frame);
    //NSRect: {{168, 102}, {5, 5}}
}
```

CORRECT SOLUTION:

```
-(void) moveTheShape:(NSTimer*)timer
{
Shape *userInfo = [timer userInfo];
NSLog(@"Info:  %@",userInfo);
CGPoint origin = userInfo.frame.origin;
NSLog(@"result: %f", origin.x);
}
```

Comment: As a general note, you should use `objectForKey:` when accessing objects stored in an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: NSDictionary *origin = [userInfo valueForKey:@"origin"];

Comment: Your userInfo looks to me like it's not an `NSDictionary`; rather it looks like a `Shape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my hunch about the type of userInfo is correct:

```
-(void) moveTheShape:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    Shape *userInfo = [timer userInfo];
    CGPoint origin = userInfo.frame.origin;
    // Do stuff with origin
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The CGRect is stored as NSValue
You will need to get the `CGRectValue` from the `NSValue`

Use The following

```
NSValue *value = [userInfo valueForKey:@"frame"];
CGRect rect = [value CGRectValue];
```

Comment: NSValue *value = [userInfo objectForKey:@"frame"];
gave me the following error: -[Shape objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: but in your code you wrote that NSLog(@"frame: %@", frame); gave you result, is the code you written correct?

Comment: I checked-- the code I wrote produces the following in an NSLog: NSRect: {{168, 102}, {5, 5}}

Answer (score 0):

int abscissa = frame.origin.x; will get you the x value. You use frame.size.width and frame.size.height to get the sizes.

Comment: This give an error: Semantic Issue: Property 'origin' not found on object of type 'NSDictionary

Comment: This line:  NSDictionary *frame = [userInfo  valueForKey:@"frame"]; is wrong.  It should be NSRect frame = [userInfo valueForKey:@"frame"];

Comment: That gave me: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSRect'

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is iOS (hmm... why did the log say NSRect?).  You should use CGRect instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, `abscissa`, my new word for the day!

Anyhow, do you mean CGRect, as an iPhone uses CoreGraphics, not FoundationKit for all UIKit rectangles.

As for the accessing the struct's internal vars (CGPoint and CGSize to be exact), just use regular old dot notation after storing the frame into a CGRect var like so:

```
NSValue *value = [userInfo objectForKey:@"frame"];
CGRect frameVar = [value CGRectValue];
frameVar.origin = CGPointMake(someCoord, someOtherCoord);
```